# Array literal as object key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference, key

I was surprised to see [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/75860/42091) to a challenge, because I had no idea this syntax was legal. Namely, the part that looks like this (I simplified it a bit):

```
"eo"[0,g=()=>{},g(),g(),1]
```

To me, this looks like an array literal is being used to access an object key. Is this documented behavior in JavaScript? For the record, it looks like the last value of the array is what gets dereferenced.

Comment: The square brackets in this case are parsed as a property accessor rather than an array literal. The commas are parsed as a [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the use of the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) for an [access](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Character_access) of a string, basically this returns `o`, and does something in between.

In parts:

```
"eo"                        string
    [                       bracket operator/string accessor
     0,                     value 0
       g=()=>{},            generating an empty function
                g(),        call that function
                    g(),    call that function again
                        1   take 1 as the last element of comma operator
                         ]  return 'o'
```

Comment: The other parts didn't confuse me, the only part I was unaware of was the legality of the comma operator inside a property accessor. By the way, that function returns `undefined`, not an empty object.

Comment: `g=()=>{}` assigns an "empty" function to *g* that when called, returns undefined. The braces `{}` are required to define the function body of an arrow function if there is no body (or multiple statements) in the same way the brackets `()` are required to define the arguments if there are zero or multiple.